# Re-pop stash at master without merging with old commit

Tags: git

I wrote some new code for my project, but for reference needed to look at an old version.

```
> git stash
> git checkout <commit of old version that I wanted to look at>
```

Afterwards I wanted to go back to work on the code I had stashed.

```
> git stash pop
```

But oops, I guess I should have checked out master first, because "git log" now shows I'm not in the most recent version anymore. So I try

```
> git checkout master

page.html: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

But I don't want to merge my stash with the old version I only peeked at. Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stash should still be there (although maybe double check with `git stash list`) since it didn't apply cleanly. So you just need to `git reset --hard HEAD` and the merge conflict will be gone so you can do the checkout.

Comment: As a note to myself, here's what I had to do: git reset --hard HEAD; git checkout master; git stash apply